# How to Handle (Escape) a % sign in mysqlclient (C Library)

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, mysql

i am using mysqlclient,

in one of my query, as shown below

```
sprintf (query, "select user from pcloud_session where id = '%s'", sid);
```

here some time this sid  is  with % sign in it like the example

```
2Cq%yo4i-ZrizGGQGQ71eJQ0
```

but when there is this %  this query always fail, i think i have to escape this %,  but how ?

i tried with \  and %% , but  both of this  not working, please help me here

**UPDATE:**

When using session.hash_bits_per_character = 6, in php session ,the default charset contains a character (comma) that will always be urlencoded(here it is %2C). This results in cookie values having this %2C in it, but session db having a comma instead of it.  any idea about fixing this problem ?.. sorry for the confusion

Thanks

Comment: As I indicated in my answer, this did not appear to be a problem with the mysqlclient libary, with MySQL needing to escape a '%' character in a literal, or with the sprintf function.

Comment: If changing hash_bits_per_character=5 is not a viable option, then if you know that the '%' character is not valid in the characterset of the derived hash value, it seems like you could urldecode the string returned from the cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to escape a literal `'%'` in MySQL query text.

When you say the query "always fail", is it the call to the `mysql_query` function that is returning an error?  Does it return a SQL Exception code, or is it just not returning the resultset (row) you expect?

For debugging, I suggest you echo out the contents of the `query` string, after the call to `sprintf`. We'd expect the contents of the string to be:

```
select user from pcloud_session where id = '2Cq%yo4i-ZrizGGQGQ71eJQ0'
```

And I don't see anything wrong with that SQL construct (assuming the `id` column exists in `pcloud_session` and is of character datatype. Even if id was defined as an integer type, that statement wouldn't normally throw an exception, the string literal would just be interpreted as integer value of 2.)

There should be no problem including a '%' literal into the target format of an sprintf. And there should be no problem including a '%' literal within MySQL query text.

(I'm assuming, of course, that `sid` is populated by a call to `mysql_real_escape_string` function.)

---

Again, I suggest you echo out the contents of `query`, following the call to sprintf. I also suggest you ensure that no other code is mucking with the contents of that string, and that is the actual string being passed as an argument to `mysql_query` function.  (If you are using the `mysql_real_query` function, then make sure you are passing the correct length.)

---

**UPDATE**

**Oxi said:**  "It does not return a SQL Exception code, it just does not return the result[set] I expect. I did print the query, it prints with % in it."

**@Oxi**

Here's a whole bunch of questions that might help you track down the problem.

Have you run a test of that query text from the mysql command line client, and does that return the row(s) you expect?

Is that `id` column defined as VARCHAR (or CHAR) with a length of (at least) 24 characters? Is the collation on the column set as case insensitive, or is it case sensitive?

```
show create table pcloud_session ;
```

(I don't see any characters in there that would cause a problem with characterset translation, although that could be a source of a problem, if your application is not matching the database charactarset encoding.)

Have you tested queries using a LIKE predicate against that id column?

```
SELECT id, user FROM pcloud_session WHERE id LIKE '2Cq\%yo4i-%' ESCAPE '\\'
 ORDER BY id LIMIT 10 ;

SELECT id, user FROM pcloud_session WHERE id LIKE '2Cq%'
 ORDER BY id LIMIT 10 ;
```

Are you getting no rows returned when you expect one row? Are you getting too many rows returned, or are you getting a different row than the one you expect?

That is an oddball value for an `id` column. At first, it looks almost as if the value is represented in a base-64 encoding, but it's not any standard encoding, since it includes the '%' and the '-' characters.

Comment: +1: Indeed there isn't anything of wrong with using the % sign inside sid, that string is just not part of the format.

Comment: it Does not return a SQL Exception code, it just does not returning the result i expect.. i did print the query, it prints with % in it.. i am still confused, Thanks

Comment: @Oxi: I updated my answer above, with way more information than would fit in a comment box. I hope something there might help.

Comment: @spencer7593 : sorry for the late reply .. i have updated my findings in the question ...  the problem is totally different,  its not an sql query escaping problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do this in C without an interface library, you **must** use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) to do proper SQL escaping.

There shouldn't be anything intrinsically wrong with using '%`inside of a string, though, as the only context in which it has meaning is either directly in`printf`type functions or as an argument to`LIKE` inside of MySQL.

This proves to be really annoying, but it's absolutely necessary. It's going to make your code a lot more complicated which is why using low-level MySQL in C is usually a bad idea. The C++ wrapper will give you a lot more support.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't escape the string yourself. The safest option is to let the MySQL API handle it for you.

For a string of maximum length n, start by allocating a string of length 2*n+1:

```
int sidLength = strlen(sid);
// worst-case, we need to escape every character, plus a byte for the ASCIIZ
int maxSafeSidLength = sidLength * 2 + 1;
char *safeSid = malloc(maxSafeSidLength);

// copy "sid" to "safeSid", escaping as appropriate
mysql_real_escape_string(mysql, safeSid, sid, sidLength);


// build the query
// ...

free(safeSid);
```

There's a longer example at the [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) page on dev.mysql.com, in which they build the entire query string, but the above approach should work for supplying safeSid to sprintf.

Comment: I'd asssumed (since the OP is using the mysqlclient library, that `sid` was the result of a call to `mysql_real_espcape_string`. Of course, that needs to happen. The OP seems to indicate that it's the '%' character that's causing the problem, and the '%' character is not a character that gets escaped.